# Parallel Algorithm to search Maximum/Minimum element in an unsorted array

Tags: parallel-processing

I'm curious to know how can we determine the maximum/minimum element in an array using multiple processors(Parallel computing) in less than O(n) time complexity?

Comment: What have you tried so far by yourself?

Comment: I thought of maintaining logn processors, and divide the array into the same number of parts. Then give each part to a single processor and do the searching for maximum element. But, after getting maximum from each processor, we again need to do the same thing?